# How do I use Google Storage in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, locking, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage

The [example code](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary#setup-python) makes use of this `oauth2_client` which it immediately locks.  The script does not work without these lines.  What's the correct way to integrate this into a Flask app?  Do I have to manage these locks?  Does it matter if my web server spawns multiple threads?  Or if I'm using gunicorn+gevent?  Is there documentation on this anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not actually locking, it's just instantiating a lock object inside the module. The lock is actually acquired/released internally by `oauth2_client`; you don't need to manage it yourself. You can see this by looking at the source code, here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/master/gslib/third_party/oauth2_plugin/oauth2_client.py

In fact, based on the source code linked above, you should be able to simply call `oauth2_client.InitializeMultiprocessingVariables()` instead of the `try/except` block, since that is ultimately doing almost the exact same thing.

Comment: On some computers, this causes an error because the global variable "manager" is not defined yet it gslib.util.